# separate UI files for multiple websites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, themes

We have a web design project. In this project we have Areas to separate Admin files, which is the same for all of our websites. We want to have multiple themes in our UI project but also  each theme should have own controllers and views for selecting and showing data for this theme. We don't want to duplicate the project for every website, because just UI, Controllers, Views and theme HTML files are different. We want to make a folder for each website that holds controllers, views and themes for it, and an option to select which one would be the default.
Is this possible?

Comment: why do you need separate controllers just for a different theme?

Comment: Because of theme structure,For example some of our themes show news in home page some other not or some websites are type of store and some others  are corporate websites, so our models are different in each theme

Comment: Look into child actions. All these subcomponent "modules" can be handled through child actions and you can have just one controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use child actions for this type of stuff. For example:

**SomeController.cs**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult News()
{
    var news = repo.News.GetLatest();
    return PartialView(news);
}
```

**News.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<NewsItem>
<ul>
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>@item.Title</li>
}
</ul>
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@Html.Action("News", "SomeController")
```

That's just a quick and dirty example, but the idea here is that now your "news" is decoupled from the current controller/action. If you want news in one layout, just add that call to `Html.Action`, and if you don't want news in one layout, just leave it out.

Comment: We can have separate actions for different type of themes,In this way we don't need to separate controllers but yet we need to separate views for each themes because of theme ,Something like CustomViewEngine should help but we don't know how

Comment: One possible solution would be to pass in the view to use as a parameter to the action: `@Html.Action("News", "SomeController", new { view = "DifferentNews" })`. Then pass this into the return: `return PartialView(view, news)`.